# References on Algebraic Operators

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $d$ is an inner derivation on $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$. An operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ is algebraic if $p(T)=0$ for some polynomial $p$.

In [their 1996 paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=/PSP/PSP120_02/S0305004100074892a.pdf&code=7290acb43defe7658a9e7b504bdd5319), Bresar and Semrl show that if $d(T)$ has finite spectrum, then $d(T)$ is algebraic (Thm3.2). This provides a link with the problem of almost invariant spaces through the derivation:\begin{equation}
d(T)=PT-TP,
\end{equation}
where $P$ is a fixed projection.

To be more specific, a subspace $Y$ is almost reducing for $T$ if $d(T)$ is of finite rank where $d$ is the derivation defined above and $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $Y$. So in particular, $PT-TP$ will be a finite rank algebraic operator.

Some particularly interesting question maybe:

1) Can we get some information concerning the invariant/ reducing subspaces from this operator?

2) If we further assume $d(T)$ is finite rank for all $T$ in an algebra of operators, can we know something about the invariant subspaces, or almost invariant subspaces of the algebra?

3) On the other direction, if for a fixed operator $T$, $PT-TP$ is of finite rank for many $P$, (eg. all $P$ in a masa) what can we say about this $T$?

However, to gain more information, some more properties about algebraic operators are needed.  Therefore I wonder whether there is some good references talking about algebraic operators. The problem is quite open and any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: In this case I think the question is too broad. Can you not at least try to pin down a focused list of *what* you want to know about algebraic operators? Otherwise you are almost asking for an encyclopaedia entry

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes. I understand that. But it's quite difficult to pin something down due to my limited knowledge about algebraic operators. But I am thinking about something concerning finite rank algebraic operators of the form $PT-TP$, where $P$ is a projection. I want to know some relation between this operator and $P$, maybe there invariant subspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since this question never got an answer I will share some references I found on this topic.

The most useful reference is [Halmos' Ten Problems in Hilbert Space](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-76/issue-5/Ten-problems-in-Hilbert-space/bams/1183532189.full), where he concluded $T\in B(\mathcal{H})$ iff $T$ is 'block upper-triangular' and all the diagonal blocks are scalars.

Also, [Radjavi and Rosenthal's Invariant Subspace book](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Invariant_Subspaces.html?id=68SRnYbWKXQC) contains good information on the connection between algebraic operators and invariant subspace problem. In particular, they showed that $T$ is algebraic iff there is a natural number $D$ such that $\mathcal{H}=\oplus_{1}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}_j$, where $dim(\mathcal{H}_j)\le D$ for all $j$.